# Pyspark Dataframe Write to delta Column name issues in partition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

when I write the spark dataframe to delta ,The column name is changing to some other value .
PLease see the below

```
silver_path=data_lake_container+"/"+ destination["folder"]
df_date.write \
        .format("delta") \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .option("header","true") \
        .option("overwriteSchema", "true") \
        .option("path", silver_path) \
        .partitionBy("X ","Y","Z ") \
        .saveAsTable('Table_name') # External table
```

But the folder has written in the below format
[image: Folder partition in delta]

Instead of X the value is comin like this .Any idea it is coming like this

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your table has [column mapping enabled](https://docs.delta.io/latest/versioning.html#column-mapping).   You can do

```sql
describe table extended Table_name
```

on that table, and you should see following table properties:

- `delta.minReaderVersion`
- `delta.minWriterVersion`
- `delta.columnMapping.mode`
- `delta.columnMapping.maxColumnId`

Comment: Will this destroy the partitioning on the table? If the partition is on dt and hr for example, will that impact performance? I thought delta reads the partitions from the transaction logs so my guess is that it should be okay.